# Move backdrop filter element behind absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

Here's the problem

```css
* {
  color: white;
}

.must-be-top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1999;
}

.v-space {
  height: 10px;
}

.blur {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
This is the blurred container
  <div class="must-be-top">This div must be on top</div>
</div>
<div class="v-space"></div>
<div class="must-be-behind blur">This div must be behind</div>
```

I'm looking for a workaround to make the red div go over the blurred div. I've already read about stacking order and painting order but couldn't come up with any solution. Any ideas?

### UPDATE

I need the red div to be on top of any element regardless of what they are, and I'm not in control of editing them.

Comment: position:relative; z-index:1 onto the first div ?

Answer (score 0):

Why is blur a parent of `must-be-top`? Changing that, and applying `z-index: -1;` to `must-be-behind` will fix your problem:

```css
* {
  color: white;
}

.must-be-top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
.v-space {
  height: 10px;
}
.blur {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
.must-be-behind {
  z-index: -1;          /* new line */
  position: relative;   /* new line */
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px) /* new line */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="blur">This is the blurred container</div> <!-- edited line -->
        <div class="must-be-top">This div must be on top</div>
        <div class="v-space"></div>
        <div class="must-be-behind blur">This div must be behind</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I just realized this solution won't work for me since I need the red div to be on top of any element regardless of what they are, and I'm not in control of editing them.

Comment: you can simply add `z-index: 0;` to the other elements right? Any element can be edited.

Comment: Should I add `z-index: 0;` to all elements in the page, including this element's parent? does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your CSS and you will get what you want:

```css
.must-be-behind {z-index:-1; position:relative;}
```

The reason is without any `z-index` defined, your `.blur` div will treat the second one higher than the first one. What I did is set the `.must-be-behind` always be behind, and to have `z-index` to work, we need a positioned element.

```css
* {
  color: white;
}

.must-be-top {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1999;
}

.v-space {
  height: 10px;
}

.blur {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
.must-be-behind {z-index:-1; position:relative;}
```

```html
<div class="blur">
This is the blurred container
  <div class="must-be-top">This div must be on top</div>
</div>
<div class="v-space"></div>
<div class="must-be-behind blur">This div must be behind</div>
```

Comment: I just realized this solution won't work for me since I need the red div to be on top of any element regardless of what they are, and I'm not in control of editing them.

Comment: "I'm looking for a workaround to make the red div go over the blurred div" - does my answer solve this original problem? And in what case do we need this -> "the red div to be on top of any element regardless of what they are"? Can you update your question with a new code snippet for this?

Comment: I updated the question but the snippet is showing the problematic case. Plus, by the blurred div I meant all blurred divs including the red div's parent, what I meant was that all of them have the same class, the `.blur` class, but anyway, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.